# SharePoint Survey with Images

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to have an image in the Survey Question?

I want my responders to choose an answer depending on the image in the question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box - no, you can't do it. However, you can create a custom field type and design a specific field control for this type (see how-to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981226.aspx)

In your case, I would create a field that inherits from the "choice" field and add some metadata to the field itself which would be used during rendering.

This seems like a good tutorial, too: http://blog.etter.nl/archive/2007/10/17/create-custom-multi-choice-field-type.aspx